# gMock method declaration parameter type mismatch

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to mock one of the method in a class. (`Randomiser_MOCK.h`)

```
#include "../src/Randomiser.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class Randomiser_MOCK : public Randomiser {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD0( getRand, unsigned long() );
    MOCK_METHOD2( setPoolRange, bool( const uint64_t &range_from, const uint64_t &range_to ) );
};
```

The header file (`Randomiser.h`) of the class in question is:

```
class Randomiser {
  public:
    Randomiser();
    Randomiser( const Randomiser &randomiser );
    Randomiser( Randomiser &&randomiser );
    bool setPoolRange( const uint64_t &range_from, const uint64_t &range_to );
    unsigned long getRand();

  private:
    std::mt19937 _rng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> _distribution;
};
```

And I'm getting this in the IDE:
[image: Result of the mock method declaration]

Which is a little weird since I've pretty much copy pasted the method signature over from the original to the mock method declaration and the `getRand()` one works just fine (inc. compile/run).

Anyone got an idea about this?

Actual unit test file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "Randomiser_MOCK.h"

#include "../src/Generator.h"
#include "../src/Generator.cpp"

TEST( Generator_Tests, create ) {
    Randomiser_MOCK r;
    using ::testing::Return;
    using ::testing::_;
    ON_CALL( r, getRand() ).WillByDefault( Return( 1 ) ); //All good here
    ON_CALL( r, setPoolRange(_,_) ).WillByDefault( Return( true ) );
    auto generator = Generator( r, "test_file" );
    generator.create();
    //....
}
```

Comment: Please state the compiler and IDE that you are using. Also, in the first code snippet, you are using `MOCK_CONST_METHOD2` but in the screenshot I see `MOCK_METHOD2`. Is this just a typo in the first code snippet?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic I'm using **CLion** with **GCC 5.3.0** (Cmake 3.5.1) on Linux. The const was a typo (now corrected).

Comment: are you using any matcher as in the code - or some other matcher?